# issue with google gmock test EXPECT_CALL(mock).WillOnce(Return())

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

```cpp
#define NULL_POINTER (int)1003
Class MyClass {
int curl_fetch_url(CURL *curl, const char *url, response_t *presponse) {
NULL_POINTER
    if (curl == NULL || url == NULL || NULL == presponse) {
        return NULL_POINTER;
    }
}
```

test code

```cpp
TEST(curl_fetch_url_1) {
   curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
   CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
   int expected_ret = NULL_POINTER;
   CurlMocker mock;
   EXPECT_CALL(mock, curl_fetch_url(curl, "", NULL)).WillOnce(Return(NULL_POINTER));
   int actual_ret = curl_fetch_url(curl, "", NULL);
   ASSERT_EQ(actual_ret, expected_ret);
   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
   curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

Actual call is made to `curl_fetch_url` to and `actual_ret` and `expected_ret` matches with expected `NULL_POINTER` i.e 1003 but still gives:

````
EXPECT_CALL(mock, curl_fetch_url(curl, "", NULL)).WillOnce(Return(NULL_POINTER))...
            Expected: to be called once
            Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active ```
````

Actual call is made to `curl_fetch_url` and I print the return in `curl_fetch_url` method as well.
Seems pretty straightforward but not sure whats wrong here. Kindly Suggest
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you forget to use `virtual` in `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass {
virtual int curl_fetch_url(CURL *curl, const char *url, response_t *presponse) {
    if (curl == NULL || url == NULL || NULL == presponse) {
        return NULL_POINTER;
    }
}
```

`CurlMocker` is not able to mock non-virtual methods. Also, I don't see `mock` being injected anywhere. You must pass this object in this line:

```
int actual_ret = curl_fetch_url(curl, "", NULL);
```

somehow.